# Create a word cloud on linux command-line

Tags: linux, command-line, images

I'd like to create a word cloud on the linux command-line, similar to wordle and similar services. How can I do that? I have plain-text files and I'd like to create a word-cloud for each one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See this word cloud generator written in Python:

https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud

It can be easily installed with pip using this command:

```
pip install wordcloud
```

Comment: Please add some content instead of just posting links

Comment: I had to use `sudo pip install wordcloud`. From there, `wordcloud_cli.py` worked from the command line. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @6005 `pip install --user wordcloud` will work fine, if you also update your `PATH` variable to include `$HOME/.local/bin` (on Linux) or `$HOME/Library/Python/X.Y/bin` (on Mac), where _X.Y_ are the major and minor versions of your Python version (check with `python -V`). [Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/) is a guide for adding a directory to the `PATH` environment variable on a Mac; "Method #1" works for Linux, too.

Answer (score 8):

```bsh
# install python package
pip install wordcloud

# show help message
wordcloud_cli --help

# a simple demo
wordcloud_cli --background white --text input.txt --imagefile output.png
```

[image]